# One Component takes response from server and shared it with all components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will be having a few component to make a dashboard. I have a servercall.js which looks like this for now.

```
class ServerCall extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      console.log(this.props);
      this.state = {num: "", response: ""};
    }

   componentDidMount() {
      const num = window.location.pathname;
      this.setState({ num: num });
   }

   componentWillMount() {
     this.setState({response: "put response here."});
   }

  render() {
    console.log("servercall props", this.props)
    return (
            <div>
                <p><br />Path from URL: {this.state.num.substring(1)}</p>
        <p>{this.state.response}</p>
            </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ServerCall;
```

This class will make an async call to the server and the response will be a pretty large json file. From there, I want to pay that response state to all of my other components so I can use the other information in it.

With that being said, I have another component that I am working on, behavior.js.

This looks like this...

```
import ServerCall from '../servercall.js';


class Behavior extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {response: ""}
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <ServerCall response={this.state.response} />

        <div className="container componentBorder">

            <div className="row heading">
                <h5>Behavior Patterns</h5>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
              <div className="scrollableDiv">
                {this.state.response}
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Behavior;
```

Response is empty... What am I missed or doing wrong here?

Comment: You may use `localStorage` or `reducer` to fix your issues

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting how state works in React. Your problem can be solved by using the flux pattern which essentially means that all of your application's state resides in a single place. This has many advantages over having state in each individual component. You should read more about Redux.

Answer (score 0):

You're structure of the components seems a little messed up. Ideally you should have one component where you do the fetching of the data. Then you have a state in that component where you store the fetched data. From this component you send down the state data to other components by using props.

Looking at your code now you send in the response to your ServerCall component from the Behavior component. And by what you want to achieve in your description above that seems wrong. The Behavior should get the response data from Servercall by props as it is the Servercall that's going to fetch the data.

I suggest you read more about props and state and how they work in React.

You could of course also use something like Redux but that's really depends on your preferences and how complex your App needs to be.